# Error 403 while trying to download an image, but not to show it

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm getting an error 403 while I try to do anything to an image's Url (be it get the file size or download it) but I don't get any error while trying to show the image.

I hope I'm clear enough, but if need be this is an example of url posing problem:

[Image URL](http://webtoon.phinf.naver.net/20160303_295/1456967418295xOyXS_JPEG/1456967418271405673.jpg) /  [Site show the image](http://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/newman/season-ii-dress-up-special/viewer?title_no=405&episode_no=67)

I'm using this code to get the file size which works great but not on this site for exemple :

```
public void getFileSize(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        waitGetSize = 0;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Timeout = 5000;
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        imgSize = resp.ContentLength;
        imgSizeKb = imgSize / 1024;
        waitGetSize = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Exception :", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

As pointed out by cFrozenDeath, I used a HEAD request, so I tried using a GET request to the exact same effect. Same result by simply not stating the request type I want.

So is there a way to get the file size or at least download the file knowing it's shown OK when opened in a browser?

Comment: sounds like you dont have permission to download the image

Comment: When you use a browser you send a GET request, not a HEAD request. There's a huge difference.

Comment: And is there a way to get the image with a GET request (I know nothing about this ^^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mimic a webbrowser when you want to scrape content from websites.

Sometimes this means you need to provide and/or keep the [`Cookies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) you get when you land initially on a website, sometimes you have to tell the webserver which page linked to the resource.

In this case you need to provide the [`Referer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) in the header:

```
public  void getFileSize(string uri)
{
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        // which page do we want that server to believe we call this from
        req.Referer = "http://www.webtoons.com/";

        req.Timeout = 5000;
        req.Method = "GET";  // or do a HEAD    
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        // rest omitted 
}
```

That particular image has a length of `273073` bytes.

Do note that scraping content might be against the terms of service of the particular website. Make sure you don't end up doing illegal stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply !
I'll also check if it's not against their ToS. 
Thanks !!